# Unspecified error when using Meteor with TypeScript

Tags: meteor, typescript, nitrousio

I'm developing a web application with Meteor and TypeScript. I'm also using the Nitrous.io cloud development environment.

I installed the TypeScript compiler and added TypeScript libraries from here: https://github.com/meteor-typescript.

I am trying to use Iron Router in my app.

The error I'm getting is:

```
/lib/package_defs/ironrouter.d.ts(80,56): error TS1005: ',' expected.
/lib/package_defs/ironrouter.d.ts(80,92): error TS1005: ',' expected.                                                                                                                                                                       

Error: Unspecified error
```

I get the same error with other packages, whenever the '|' character is used. For example, line 80 of ironrouter.d.ts is:

```
export function onBeforeAction(hookOrFunc?: string | Function, funcOrParams?: Function | any, params?: any): void;
```

I tried changing all '|' to ',' like the error message suggests, but then I get another error message:

```
/lib/package_defs/ironrouter.d.ts(80,58): error TS1016: Required parameter cannot follow optional parameter.                                                                                                                                

Error: Unspecified error
```

I'm no expert and I'm new to TypeScript and Meteor. 
What could be causing this error? Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Try to update your Typescript version to 1.4 - https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2d42d8dc-e085-45eb-a30b-3f7d50d55304

Comment: I am using version 1.4. 

Anyway, I just noticed that the errors seem to be caused by the latest commit: 

https://github.com/meteor-typescript/meteor-typescript-libs/commit/5a48d8a66f23e50d9469c0c1e59bf3506feaf5a1

I undid these changes and now I'm not getting any errors!

Comment: @Bartek I wonder if it's caused by the use of union types, which are a new addition in 1.4. If so you may want to ensure you really do have 1.4 installed (it personally took me a while to get it right). In either case, feel free to add your solution as an answer to your own question. That's totally fine to do on StackOverflow. :)

Comment: I just made sure, and the version of TypeScript is definitely 1.4.1.0. Now I am trying to use the meteor.d.ts library and I'm getting a massive amount of errors again... So, I went on GitHub, and tried all the versions that were committed. Only the oldest one works!
 
This is very weird. I realise that what's causing errors should work as it was updated specifically for TypeScript version 1.4. I will keep trying to figure this out.
If anybody has any ideas please let me know, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Union types were added in version 1.4 of TypeScript and are used in the definition file you mention:

```
export function onBeforeAction(hookOrFunc?: string | Function, funcOrParams?: Function | any, params?: any): void;
```

If you have already installed version 1.4 or above, make sure your project is using it (view you project file):

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.4</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```

If you are still certain that you are using version 1.4, check that you can use the new features using this snippet:

```
type example = string | number;
```

You can [track support for TypeScript 1.4 in WebStorm here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14151).

Comment: I'm using WebStorm locally for programming, and I just found out that it doesn't yet support TypeScript v1.4, so that's why it gives out errors. However, I don't understand why that would matter though, since I'm using nitrous.io and I definitely have ts 1.4.1.0 installed there, but it's still giving me errors...

Comment: I'm not a nitrous expert - but perhaps the IDE you are using on there also lacks support for 1.4?